# mule 3.3.1 threading profile

Tags: mule

I use mule 3.3.1 CE .

I see that UDP connector is not receiving the traffic with the following threading profile settings

```
<udp:connector name="udpConnector" receiveBufferSize="1024" sendBufferSize="1024">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="5" maxBufferSize="5"/>
</udp:connector>
```

The issue stays the same when I moved it up to the configuration level

```
<configuration>
   <default-receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="5" maxBufferSize="5"/>
</configuration>
<udp:connector name="udpConnector" receiveBufferSize="1024" sendBufferSize="1024"/>
```

However , mule starts receiving traffic with out threading profile settings

```
<udp:connector name="udpConnector" receiveBufferSize="1024" sendBufferSize="1024"/>
```

I am not sure if the issue is specific with mule 3.3.1.

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bug raised about something similar before. There is a bug when defining the values for maxBufferSize and poolExhaustedAction in the threading profile configuration without defining the "maxThreadsIdle" attribute.

However if you set the maxThreadsIdle to any value higher than 1 in your threading profile the problem should be solved. This could be the same issue.

Comment: Thanks @RyanCarter. Issue fixed by setting maxThreadsIdle ...
<udp:connector name="udpConnector" receiveBufferSize="1024" sendBufferSize="1024">
   <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="5" maxThreadsIdle="2" maxBufferSize="5"/>
</udp:connector>